# Register form no hace POST

Tags: php, mysql

Es un error muy simple, pero no logro entender porque no hace POST... solo funciona el php cuando lo coloco en la misma pagina, quiero hacer que funcione desde afuera de esta

Esta la forma que tengo.

```
       <form id="formRegistro" action="complementos/registro_function.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="registro_nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[0]; ?>">
          </div>                 
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="registro_apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[1]; ?>">
          </div>                 
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" id="registro_telefono" name="registro_telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[2]; ?>">
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registro_email" name="registro_email" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[3]; ?>">
          </div>                      
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registro_username" name="registro_username" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[4]; ?>">
          </div>                                                      
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registro_password" name="registro_password" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[5]; ?>">
            <span class="label label-default" id="registro_password_label"></span>
          </div>   
          <div class="form-group" >
          <select class="form-control b-dropdown" id="registro_pais" name="registro_pais">
               <?php
                $i=0;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
          <option value="<?=$row["paises_id"];?>"><?=$row["paises_name"];?></option>
                <?php
                $i++;
              }
               ?>
               <?php
                mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
          </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control b-dropdown" id="registro_centro" name="registro_centro">
                <?php
                 $i=0;
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
               ?>
          <option value="<?=$row["centros_id"];?>"><?=$row["centros_nombre"];?></option>
                  <?php
                   $i++;
                   }
                    ?>
                  <?php
                  mysqli_close($conn);
                   ?>
          </select>
          </div>                
        </form>      
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-full" id="Meter" type="submit" class="floated" value="Meter"><?php echo $btnOpciones[0]; ?></button>
```

Ya sospecho que debo tener un problema con los selects, los cuales se traen los datos de la base de datos para que el usuario los pueda insertar por alli.

Este es el codigo que alimenta los select, los cuales traen datos. La parte de traer los datos si funciona pero me pregunto si es que mi funcion para insertar los datos no esta agarrando los datos de los select y cree que estan vacios

```
    <?php
    require_once('conexion.class.php');
    $conn = DBManager::con();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sm_paises ORDER BY paises_name");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sm_centros ORDER BY centros_nombre");
    ?>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en registro_function.php. Como pueden ver, tiene un metodo para evitar de que haya algun dato vacio. Lo removi e igualmente no hizo POST, si preguntan

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../function/class/conexion.class.php');
$db = DBManager::con();

$_POST['registro_nombre'] = $registro_nombre;
$_POST['registro_apellido'] = $registro_apellido;
$_POST['registro_telefono'] = $registro_telefono;
$_POST['registro_email'] = $registro_email;
$_POST['registro_username'] = $registro_username;
$_POST['registro_password'] = $registro_password;
$_POST['registro_centro'] = $registro_centro;

$reqlen = strlen($registro_nombre) + strlen($registro_apellido) + strlen($registro_telefono) 
+ strlen($registro_email) + strlen($registro_username) + strlen($registro_password) + strlen($registro_centro);

  if($reqlen > 0){
    $registro_password = md5($registro_password);    //Convierte la clave en md5
    $query = "INSERT INTO `reto_registro`
    VALUES ('', '$registro_nombre', '$registro_apellido', 
    '$registro_telefono', '$registro_email', '$registro_username', 
    '$registro_password', '$registro_centro', '1', '0', '0', '1')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $res = "Se ha registrado exitosamente";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$res');</script>";

  }else{
    $res = 'Por favor rellene los espacios necesarios';  
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$res');</script>";
  }
?>
```

Esta es la estructura de la tabla MYSQL de PHPMYADMIN

```
CREATE TABLE `reto_registro` (
  `registro_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `registro_nombre` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registro_apellido` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registro_telefono` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registro_email` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registro_username` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registro_password` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registro_centro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `registro_estatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `registro_puntos` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `registro_eliminado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `registro_nivel` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: No hace POST... ¿No hace el submit? ¿Cuál es la respuesta del servidor (Response Code)?

Comment: No logro hacer que funcione echo var_dump. Pero al usar el debbuger, me dice que no consigue las variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que asignar a una variable el valor obtenido por POST y no al revés.

Es decir:

```
$variable = $_POST['campo'];
//en tu caso
$registro_nombre = $_POST['registro_nombre'];
```

Si lo haces al revés (lo que tienes ahora)

```
$_POST['registro_nombre'] = $registro_nombre;
```

En realidad estas diciendo que asigne el valor del la variable $registro_nombre al campo obtenido por POST y por eso no puedes obtener el valor de los campos.

Comment: Hice eso y no hace POST igualmente

Comment: ¿La ruta del "action" es correcta? Me refiero a que no le falte ningún ./ o ../ delante

Comment: Si es correcta. Incluso puse el codigo php en el mismo html y no hizo post

Comment: Mete el código del button antes de la etiqueta </form>, no había visto que estás haciendo "submit" desde un botón que está fuera del formulario.

Comment: Debe ser eso. Lo intentare